# org.apache.spark.SparkException: A master URL must be set in your configuration

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I get `org.apache.spark.SparkException: A master URL must be set in your configuration` ERROR.

It occurs on an executor not a driver.

I get `========conf========` print correctly which I logged after starting sparksession

But when I do partitioning on Dataset and try to do some action, I get error as executor fails to create SparkSession.
(If I call `collect()` instead of `coalesce(3)`, the job succeeds.)

I can't find any solution.

Below is my spark APP.

```scala
    val builder: SparkSession.Builder = SparkSession.builder().enableHiveSupport()
    _spark = builder.getOrCreate()
```

```scala
    println("================START================")
    println(s"=========profile:${ProfileUtils.getEnvironment()}============")
    println("========conf========")

    val odsBundles = findBundles()

    odsBundles.coalesce(3).foreach((row: Row) => {
      val bundleLifecycleIdKey = s"${row.getAs[Long]("bundleId")}:${mapBundleType(row.getAs[String]("shippingDeliveryType"))}"
      val newBundleLifecycleId: UUID = UUID.nameUUIDFromBytes(bundleLifecycleIdKey.getBytes())
      println(s"@@@@@@ find: ${newBundleLifecycleId.toString}")
    })

    println("================END================")
```

Driver error

```
22/02/18 16:40:33 INFO cluster.YarnClusterScheduler: Cancelling stage 4
22/02/18 16:40:33 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: ResultStage 4 (foreach at BundleMappingCheckApp.scala:73) failed in 9.881 s due to Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 4.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 4.0 (TID 2595, ip-10-211-213-216.ap-northeast-2.compute.internal, executor 2): java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.coupang.flow.validation.spark.app.bundle.BundleMappingCheckApp$$anonfun$runApp$1.apply(BundleMappingCheckApp.scala:74)
    at com.coupang.flow.validation.spark.app.bundle.BundleMappingCheckApp$$anonfun$runApp$1.apply(BundleMappingCheckApp.scala:73)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1336)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreach$1$$anonfun$apply$28.apply(RDD.scala:927)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreach$1$$anonfun$apply$28.apply(RDD.scala:927)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:2074)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:2074)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:109)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:345)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: A master URL must be set in your configuration
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:367)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$.getOrCreate(SparkContext.scala:2493)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder$$anonfun$7.apply(SparkSession.scala:934)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder$$anonfun$7.apply(SparkSession.scala:925)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.getOrCreate(SparkSession.scala:925)
    at com.coupang.flow.validation.spark.app.bundle.BundleMappingCheckApp$.initializeContext(BundleMappingCheckApp.scala:29)
    at com.coupang.flow.validation.base.spark.app.BaseSparkApp$class.$init$(BaseSparkApp.scala:12)
    at com.coupang.flow.validation.spark.app.bundle.BundleMappingCheckApp$.<init>(BundleMappingCheckApp.scala:12)
    at com.coupang.flow.validation.spark.app.bundle.BundleMappingCheckApp$.<clinit>(BundleMappingCheckApp.scala:48)
    ... 14 more

Driver stacktrace:
22/02/18 16:40:33 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Job 0 failed: foreach at BundleMappingCheckApp.scala:73, took 94.454855 s
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 4.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 4.0 (TID 2595, ip-10-211-213-216.ap-northeast-2.compute.internal, executor 2): java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.coupang.flow.validation.spark.app.bundle.BundleMappingCheckApp$$anonfun$runApp$1.apply(BundleMappingCheckApp.scala:74)
    at com.coupang.flow.validation.spark.app.bundle.BundleMappingCheckApp$$anonfun$runApp$1.apply(BundleMappingCheckApp.scala:73)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1336)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreach$1$$anonfun$apply$28.apply(RDD.scala:927)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreach$1$$anonfun$apply$28.apply(RDD.scala:927)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:2074)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:2074)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:109)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:345)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: A master URL must be set in your configuration
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:367)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$.getOrCreate(SparkContext.scala:2493)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder$$anonfun$7.apply(SparkSession.scala:934)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder$$anonfun$7.apply(SparkSession.scala:925)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.getOrCreate(SparkSession.scala:925)
    at com.coupang.flow.validation.spark.app.bundle.BundleMappingCheckApp$.initializeContext(BundleMappingCheckApp.scala:29)
    at com.coupang.flow.validation.base.spark.app.BaseSparkApp$class.$init$(BaseSparkApp.scala:12)
    at com.coupang.flow.validation.spark.app.bundle.BundleMappingCheckApp$.<init>(BundleMappingCheckApp.scala:12)
    at com.coupang.flow.validation.spark.app.bundle.BundleMappingCheckApp$.<clinit>(BundleMappingCheckApp.scala:48)
    ... 14 more

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1803)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1791)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1790)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1790)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:871)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:871)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:871)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2024)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1973)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1962)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:682)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2034)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2055)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2074)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2099)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(RDD.scala:927)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(RDD.scala:925)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:363)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.foreach(RDD.scala:925)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply$mcV$sp(Dataset.scala:2661)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2661)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2661)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$withNewRDDExecutionId$1.apply(Dataset.scala:3244)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:77)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withNewRDDExecutionId(Dataset.scala:3240)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.foreach(Dataset.scala:2660)
    at com.coupang.flow.validation.spark.app.bundle.BundleMappingCheckApp$.runApp(BundleMappingCheckApp.scala:73)
    at com.coupang.flow.validation.spark.app.bundle.BundleMappingCheckApp$.main(BundleMappingCheckApp.scala:51)
    at com.coupang.flow.validation.spark.app.bundle.BundleMappingCheckApp.main(BundleMappingCheckApp.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anon$4.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:721)
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.coupang.flow.validation.spark.app.bundle.BundleMappingCheckApp$$anonfun$runApp$1.apply(BundleMappingCheckApp.scala:74)
    at com.coupang.flow.validation.spark.app.bundle.BundleMappingCheckApp$$anonfun$runApp$1.apply(BundleMappingCheckApp.scala:73)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1336)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreach$1$$anonfun$apply$28.apply(RDD.scala:927)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreach$1$$anonfun$apply$28.apply(RDD.scala:927)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:2074)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:2074)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:109)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:345)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: A master URL must be set in your configuration
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:367)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$.getOrCreate(SparkContext.scala:2493)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder$$anonfun$7.apply(SparkSession.scala:934)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder$$anonfun$7.apply(SparkSession.scala:925)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.getOrCreate(SparkSession.scala:925)
    at com.coupang.flow.validation.spark.app.bundle.BundleMappingCheckApp$.initializeContext(BundleMappingCheckApp.scala:29)
    at com.coupang.flow.validation.base.spark.app.BaseSparkApp$class.$init$(BaseSparkApp.scala:12)
    at com.coupang.flow.validation.spark.app.bundle.BundleMappingCheckApp$.<init>(BundleMappingCheckApp.scala:12)
    at com.coupang.flow.validation.spark.app.bundle.BundleMappingCheckApp$.<clinit>(BundleMappingCheckApp.scala:48)
    ... 14 more
22/02/18 16:40:33 ERROR yarn.ApplicationMaster: User class threw exception: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 4.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 4.0 (TID 2595, ip-10-211-213-216.ap-northeast-2.compute.internal, executor 2): java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.coupang.flow.validation.spark.app.bundle.BundleMappingCheckApp$$anonfun$runApp$1.apply(BundleMappingCheckApp.scala:74)
    at com.coupang.flow.validation.spark.app.bundle.BundleMappingCheckApp$$anonfun$runApp$1.apply(BundleMappingCheckApp.scala:73)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1336)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreach$1$$anonfun$apply$28.apply(RDD.scala:927)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreach$1$$anonfun$apply$28.apply(RDD.scala:927)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:2074)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:2074)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:109)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:345)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: A master URL must be set in your configuration
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:367)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$.getOrCreate(SparkContext.scala:2493)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder$$anonfun$7.apply(SparkSession.scala:934)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder$$anonfun$7.apply(SparkSession.scala:925)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.getOrCreate(SparkSession.scala:925)
    at com.coupang.flow.validation.spark.app.bundle.BundleMappingCheckApp$.initializeContext(BundleMappingCheckApp.scala:29)
    at com.coupang.flow.validation.base.spark.app.BaseSparkApp$class.$init$(BaseSparkApp.scala:12)
    at com.coupang.flow.validation.spark.app.bundle.BundleMappingCheckApp$.<init>(BundleMappingCheckApp.scala:12)
    at com.coupang.flow.validation.spark.app.bundle.BundleMappingCheckApp$.<clinit>(BundleMappingCheckApp.scala:48)
    ... 14 more
```

Executor error

```
22/02/18 16:40:33 ERROR spark.SparkContext: Error initializing SparkContext.
org.apache.spark.SparkException: A master URL must be set in your configuration
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:367)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$.getOrCreate(SparkContext.scala:2493)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder$$anonfun$7.apply(SparkSession.scala:934)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder$$anonfun$7.apply(SparkSession.scala:925)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.getOrCreate(SparkSession.scala:925)
    at com.coupang.flow.validation.spark.app.bundle.BundleMappingCheckApp$.initializeContext(BundleMappingCheckApp.scala:29)
    at com.coupang.flow.validation.base.spark.app.BaseSparkApp$class.$init$(BaseSparkApp.scala:12)
    at com.coupang.flow.validation.spark.app.bundle.BundleMappingCheckApp$.<init>(BundleMappingCheckApp.scala:12)
    at com.coupang.flow.validation.spark.app.bundle.BundleMappingCheckApp$.<clinit>(BundleMappingCheckApp.scala:48)
    at com.coupang.flow.validation.spark.app.bundle.BundleMappingCheckApp$$anonfun$runApp$1.apply(BundleMappingCheckApp.scala:74)
    at com.coupang.flow.validation.spark.app.bundle.BundleMappingCheckApp$$anonfun$runApp$1.apply(BundleMappingCheckApp.scala:73)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1336)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreach$1$$anonfun$apply$28.apply(RDD.scala:927)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreach$1$$anonfun$apply$28.apply(RDD.scala:927)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:2074)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:2074)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:109)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:345)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
22/02/18 16:40:33 ERROR util.Utils: Uncaught exception in thread Executor task launch worker for task 2595
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.org$apache$spark$SparkContext$$postApplicationEnd(SparkContext.scala:2389)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$stop$1.apply$mcV$sp(SparkContext.scala:1904)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryLogNonFatalError(Utils.scala:1361)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.stop(SparkContext.scala:1903)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:579)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$.getOrCreate(SparkContext.scala:2493)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder$$anonfun$7.apply(SparkSession.scala:934)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder$$anonfun$7.apply(SparkSession.scala:925)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.getOrCreate(SparkSession.scala:925)
    at com.coupang.flow.validation.spark.app.bundle.BundleMappingCheckApp$.initializeContext(BundleMappingCheckApp.scala:29)
    at com.coupang.flow.validation.base.spark.app.BaseSparkApp$class.$init$(BaseSparkApp.scala:12)
    at com.coupang.flow.validation.spark.app.bundle.BundleMappingCheckApp$.<init>(BundleMappingCheckApp.scala:12)
    at com.coupang.flow.validation.spark.app.bundle.BundleMappingCheckApp$.<clinit>(BundleMappingCheckApp.scala:48)
    at com.coupang.flow.validation.spark.app.bundle.BundleMappingCheckApp$$anonfun$runApp$1.apply(BundleMappingCheckApp.scala:74)
    at com.coupang.flow.validation.spark.app.bundle.BundleMappingCheckApp$$anonfun$runApp$1.apply(BundleMappingCheckApp.scala:73)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1336)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreach$1$$anonfun$apply$28.apply(RDD.scala:927)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreach$1$$anonfun$apply$28.apply(RDD.scala:927)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:2074)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:2074)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:109)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:345)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
22/02/18 16:40:33 INFO spark.SparkContext: Successfully stopped SparkContext
22/02/18 16:40:33 ERROR executor.Executor: Exception in task 0.3 in stage 4.0 (TID 2595)
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.coupang.flow.validation.spark.app.bundle.BundleMappingCheckApp$$anonfun$runApp$1.apply(BundleMappingCheckApp.scala:74)
    at com.coupang.flow.validation.spark.app.bundle.BundleMappingCheckApp$$anonfun$runApp$1.apply(BundleMappingCheckApp.scala:73)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1336)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreach$1$$anonfun$apply$28.apply(RDD.scala:927)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreach$1$$anonfun$apply$28.apply(RDD.scala:927)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:2074)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:2074)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:109)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:345)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: A master URL must be set in your configuration
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:367)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$.getOrCreate(SparkContext.scala:2493)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder$$anonfun$7.apply(SparkSession.scala:934)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder$$anonfun$7.apply(SparkSession.scala:925)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.getOrCreate(SparkSession.scala:925)
    at com.coupang.flow.validation.spark.app.bundle.BundleMappingCheckApp$.initializeContext(BundleMappingCheckApp.scala:29)
    at com.coupang.flow.validation.base.spark.app.BaseSparkApp$class.$init$(BaseSparkApp.scala:12)
    at com.coupang.flow.validation.spark.app.bundle.BundleMappingCheckApp$.<init>(BundleMappingCheckApp.scala:12)
    at com.coupang.flow.validation.spark.app.bundle.BundleMappingCheckApp$.<clinit>(BundleMappingCheckApp.scala:48)
    ... 14 more
22/02/18 16:40:33 INFO executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend: Driver commanded a shutdown
```

Comment: It would be nice if you post the complete stack trace

Comment: I added stack trace. Thanks! @Aditya